# Facet wrap loses datetime format on x axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, ggplot2, python-ggplot

When trying to facet wrap dataframe with dates on the x axis and values on the y axis, the dates all lose format. The relevant code below produces the attached graph. Any workarounds or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Updated: I've included a snapshot of the melted dataframe.

```
    rx_all.head()
        Date            Stock Period           Returns
0 2010-02-10  BIIB_ANL PERF_1  0.005546
1 2010-02-11  BIIB_ANL PERF_1  0.029448
2 2010-02-12  BIIB_ANL PERF_1  0.020829
3 2010-02-16  BIIB_ANL PERF_1  0.019198
4 2010-02-17  BIIB_ANL PERF_1  0.039336

[5 rows x 3 columns]

perfChart = ggplot(aes(x='Date', y='Returns', color='Stock Period'),data=rx_all) \
+ geom_line() \
+ facet_wrap('Stock Period')
```

[image: Facet Wrap stock return plot]

Comment: Does `+ scale_x_date()` help?

Comment: @Jasc nope same output.

Comment: Then it's a bug. It would be great if you could add a bugreport at https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/ with a reproduceable example.

Comment: This is now tracked in https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/295

Answer (score 0):

Try this function: scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("6 hour"), labels = date_format("%H:%M", tz="GMT5.5"))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).